# Different behavior across domain objects for same properties in Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to .NET Core and using EF Core 2

My domain objects are all derived from a base class with some audit fields on it that get set on `SaveChanges` as needed:
(Simplified below)

```
public abstract class AuditableEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public Guid? CreatedByWebUserId { get; set; }
    public WebUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UpdatedBy")]
    public Guid? UpdatedByWebUserId { get; set; }
    public WebUser UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DeletedBy")]
    public Guid? DeletedByWebUserId { get; set; }
    public WebUser DeletedBy { get; set; }
}
```

On add-migration, I get the error:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 
'Address.CreatedBy' of type 'WebUser'. Either manually configure the 
relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by 
using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

`Address` is one of the classes derived from `AuditableEntity`:
(Simplified below)

```
public class Address : AuditableEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

However, I have several objects that use the same "agent and timestamp" pair pattern similar to the above that work just fine such as:

```
    public DateTime? VerifiedOn { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VerifiedBy")]
    public Guid? VerifiedByWebUserId { get; set; }
    public WebUser VerifiedBy { get; set; }
```

The error always comes from `Address`, and if I remove the base class from Address everything works fine (meaning, these fields get successfully applied to my 15+ other domain objects).

The issue seemingly stems from `WebUser` having a reference to `Address`:
(Simplified below)

```
public class WebUser : AuditableEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone1Type { get; set; }
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }
    public string Phone2Type { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Guid? AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

What is the correct way of creating these references prioritizing keeping the FK constraints (over keeping the ability to navigate)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is unrelated to the usage of a base class (the same will happen if you remove the base class, *but copy its properties* to `Address` class), but the multiple cross references between the two classes.

By convention EF Core tries to automatically "pair" navigation properties of the two entities in order to form a single relationship, which succeeds in most of the cases. However in this case the `WebUser` has `Address` type navigation property and `Address` class has `WebUser` type navigation property (actually 3).

Since all they have associated FK property via `ForeignKey` data annotation, EF Core should be able to correctly identify them as different one-to-many relationships, but it doesn't. Not only it fails with the exception in question, but also doesn't create FK relationships for the `WebUser`.

Everything works correctly if the base class contains only 1 `WebUser` type of navigation property, so I'm assuming thet unfortunately you are hitting some current EF Core bug.

As a workaround until they fixed it, I would suggest explicitly configuring the problematic relationships using fluent API, by overriding the `OnModelCreating` and adding the following code:

```
var auditableEntityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => t.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AuditableEntity)));
var webUserNavigations = new[] { nameof(AuditableEntity.CreatedBy), nameof(AuditableEntity.DeletedBy), nameof(AuditableEntity.UpdatedBy) };
foreach (var entityType in auditableEntityTypes)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType, builder =>
    {
        foreach (var webUserNavigation in webUserNavigations)
            builder.HasOne(typeof(WebUser), webUserNavigation).WithMany();
    });
}
```

i.e. for each entity class that derives from `AuditableEntity` we explicitly configure the 3 `WebUser` reference navigation properties to be mapped to 3 separate one-to-many relationships with no inverse collection navigation properties. Once we do that, EF Core has no problem to correctly map the `WebUser.Address` FK association.

Comment: add-migration now runs successfully, but on update-database, I now get the error:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Addresses_WebUsers_Id' on table 'Addresses' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. 
AuditableEntity now has only the DateTime and WebUser properties (with the Guids removed)

Comment: Hmm, there should not be a constraint named  'FK_Addresses_WebUsers_Id' at all. Do you have navigation properties of type `Address` / `WebUser` (reference or collections) not shown there? Also what happens if you add `modelBuilder.Entity<WebUser>().HasOne(u => u.Address).WithMany();` (it wasn't required in my test, EF Core 2.1 btw)?

Comment: None, all the fields left off the code are primitives.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't reproduce on my end. I'm getting 3 FK constraints named "FK_Addresses_WebUsers_CreatedByWebUserId", "FK_Addresses_WebUsers_DeletedByWebUserId", "FK_Addresses_WebUsers_UpdatedByWebUserId", all having `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict`. I wish I could help, but it's impossible w/o the repro (which wasn't the case with the initial issue).

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna keep trying commenting out some fields and update on the results.

Comment: Thanks again, I got myself in an "dirty" state with so many migrations and database updates. I started from scratch removing all migrations, deleting the database, and running a clean initial migration and update-database and it works exactly as expected with your Fluent API implementation. I do worry about having to make these type of updates in the future when I'm past prototyping!